# to get the Value from LWC in Middle of Conversation of Einstein Bot

Tags: lightning-web-components, einstein-chatbot

[image]Used LWC in Einstein bot in middle of a conversation in which user input in the text box of LWC. whatever user input in LWC wants to get that value and show on bot-message how can do that??
so if user put in all three input text and press submit it should show in chat message what user entered.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated please check @Community